Error when building netifaces: unresolved external symbol PyUnicode_FromUnicode
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.exp
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyUnicode_FromUnicode
      build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. 
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects  

This is the error message I get, I already have visual studio installed.
Been stuck on this and i need help.
I installed the netifaces package and it still doesn't work.

Impossible to help you without actual error output. "link failed" could mean anything.

Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.exp
netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyUnicode_FromUnicode
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. Is this what you mean by the error output?

PyUnicode_FromUnicode was removed in Python 3.12 after being deprecated in 3.11:

Legacy Unicode APIs have been removed. See PEP 623 for detail.

PyUnicode_WCHAR_KIND
PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE()
PyUnicode_AsUnicode()
PyUnicode_AsUnicodeAndSize()
PyUnicode_AS_DATA()
PyUnicode_FromUnicode()
PyUnicode_GET_SIZE()
PyUnicode_GetSize()
PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE()


You will have to find a version of the module that uses another function, patch it yourself, or find another module altogether.
